# Como usar o textwatcher?

Tags: android

Como usar o textwatcher para contar quantos caracteres tem em uma textview ,e mostrar em contagem regressiva , igual é feito no facebook limitando uma postagem.
Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja um exemplo de limitação de 150 caracteres (apenas visualmente):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int aft)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        textView.setText(150 - s.toString().length() + "/150");
    }
});
```

Sendo assim, logo depois depois basta fazer uma condição para que não deixe enviar os dados caso o `EditText` possua mais que a quantidade de caracteres definida previamente.

Veja abaixo como ficaria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ack, ai aparece aquela textview fazendo aquela contagem em quanto digita?

Comment: Você pode criar um TextView independente para mostrar a contagem.

Comment: Ou você queria mostrar de outra forma?

Comment: uma editText e uma textView

Comment: a textView pega a contagem...

Comment: assim entendi, Obrigado

Comment: @WallaceRoberto viu a imagem que coloquei. O EditText em cima com um TextView em baixo fazendo a contagem. =D

Comment: Show, muito bom,exatamente isso que quero!